# Regression Model with dummyvariables

Tags: statistics, finance, regression, regression-analysis

My name is Peter and I'm writing my dissertation atm. I am analysing Morningstars rating system of funds(They rate funds with stars between 1-5, depending on how good they are).

What we are trying to investigate how much each star contributes to in expected future returns.

This is how i thought i could write the regression model:

y = b_0 + b_1STAR(1) + b_2STAR(2) + b_3STAR(3) + b_4STAR(4) + b_5STAR(5) + e_t

Where; y is the expected future returns; beta parameters are dummy-variables i.e have value 0 or 1; and STAR(i) represent how much each extra each STAR predicts in future returns.

What we have data on is:
Expected future returns for funds
Number of stars each fund has
The value of each fund

How do i find the values for the STAR(i) variables? 
What confuses me is that usually when I've done regression, I've been interested in finding out the value of beta parameters.

Kind Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want to know "how much each star contributes to expected
future returns," it seems to me you have decided to regard the number of
stars as a meaningful numerical variable. To me that would imply the model
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + e_i,$$
where $x_i$ is the number of stars and $e_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$

If you want to treat the number of stars as a categorical variable, then
you might feel more comfortable with an ANOVA design
$$X_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + e_{ij},$$
where $i = 1,2,3,4,5,$ the $\alpha_i$ are the effects for each
number of stars, and $e_{ij} \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,\sigma).$ Also, $j = 1, \dots, n_i,$ where there $n_i$ is the
number of funds with $i$ stars. Then, if the main ANOVA F-test finds
differences among the effects $\alpha_i,$ you could investigate
relationships among the number of stars with linear and quadratic contrasts (to
the extent you feel categories are roughly numerical).
You might also do a Welch-style ANOVA if it seems variabilities are
different for each $i$ (which would not surprise me).

It seems to me your regression model is an ANOVA in disguise, and that may account for your difficulty interpreting the results. In any case, I hope
I have given you some alternative models that may help you clarify the
connection between your data and the appropriate model for analysis.

Comment: Hello, regarding your first regression. y = b_0 + b_1X + e. If we were to estimate b_1, then that would mean that every star contributes with the same amount of additional returns. We want to investigate how much each individual star contributes with.

Comment: The five averages of the future returns corresponding to each number of stars is the most direct measure of the results associated with each number of stars. Don't fall into the trap of thinking that the stars are _causing_ returns. In some sense the quality and mgmt of each fund may 'cause' returns. One hopes Morningstar's judgments in assigning stars reflect quality and mgmt. After the ANOVA you can use 'multiple comparison procedures' and 'contrasts' to assess different returns for different numbers of stars. (I think regression with _only_ a categorical predictor variable is a bad idea.)